# jquery code to filter out table rows if column contains word

Tags: jquery

I have some code that takes a search query (using jquery), and uses that query to filter out rows in a table. So, if I type “leather” … it looks for rows that contain “leather” and hides rows that do not contain the word. The problem that I have, is that I only want to search the first column (but it searches every column in the row). Here is a codepen of the current code

https://codepen.io/jabbamonkey/pen/yLxBOJR

(the row containing “hide” should not appear when I search for “leather” … but it does because of "leather"worker is in column 5 …)

and here is the jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.search').on('keyup',function(){
            var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            $('#craftTbl div.contentrow').each(function(){
                var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
                if(lineStr.indexOf(searchTerm) === -1){
                    $(this).hide();
                    $(".descexpand").hide();
                    $(".rowCat").hide();
                    $(".rowSec").hide();
                }else{
                    $(this).show();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

I cant seem to get the jquery code to search only “col1” and hide the ENTIRE row  when the search query is missing from that row. I do not know javascript well (at all), so any help and guidance is appreciated ...

Note: .rowCat and .rowSec and descexpand refer to entire rows that are hidden from the search completely (and aren't shown in the codepen). These work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply edit the `lineStr` assignment to get the value from the `.col1` element only:

```
var lineStr = $(this).find('.col1').text().toLowerCase();
```

Here is a [fork](https://codepen.io/76484/pen/wvEwGjj) of your CodePen as an example.

Comment: Awesome! You're the greatest!

Answer (score 0):

For each line, you could search in the first child of `$this` by substituting

```
var lineStr = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
```

with

```
var lineStr = $(this).children(":first").text().toLowerCase();
```